# "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findAll'"

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am currently writing a web-scraping script with Python to be able to take play-by-play soccer commentary from fixtures and inputting it into an excel sheet. I keep getting this when I try to run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/noahhollander/Desktop/Web_Scraping/play_by_play.py", line 9, in <module>
    tbody = soup('table',{"class":"content"})[0:].findAll('tr')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findAll'
[Finished in 6.207s]
```

I've read that this probably has something to do with this table being text format, but I have added .text at the end and still same result.

[Here is a picture of my code so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoS3i.png)

Comment: It is simply saying, you cannot perform findAll on a list.

Comment: `soup('table',{"class":"content"})[0:]` try: `soup('table',{"class":"content"})[0]` i.e try your code on one element first. when you do `[0:]` you are taking all things from your ``soup('table',{"class":"content"})` list

Comment: Your question should be why there is a list in the first place. However, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, extract a [mcve] from your code and post that inline here. Do not post pictures of text! Consider deleting your question until you have those preparations done.

Comment: Maybe tell which part of the site your trying to get as there are 6 tables on that page and none of them have class called content

Comment: always put code, data and errors as text, not image. Python can't read image with code - so it is useless.

Comment: why do you use `[0:]` ? if you want first element then use `[0]` or `soup.find('table',{"class":"content"})`. If you want to search in all tables then you will need `for`-loop

Comment: When I used [0] with this command: tbody = soup('table', {"class":"content"})[0].find_all I get list index out of range

Comment: https://www.espn.com/soccer/commentary?gameId=554346 this is an example of play-by-play I am looking at

Comment: From further reading, I now get I can't findAll on a list, so how would implement my code? with a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to write something like this.

```
soup.find_all('table',{"class":"content"})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tbody = []
tclass = soup('table', {"class":"content"})[0:]
for temp in tclass:
    for t_temp in temp.find_all('tr'):
        tbody.append(t_temp)
```

This is your desired result?

Comment: When I run with this code, it does run but get no output/tbody is empty.

Comment: That url you mention has no claass has name as content so that you will get empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
div = soup.find('div', {"class": "content"})
tbody = div.find('table').findAll('tr')
```

You will get your desired result